# Sum of cells above and below a MAX cell, within a range of cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am looking for a formula to sum the cells above a MAX cell as well as below.  Simply, if i ahve the below values:
5
10
15
20
15
10
5

...i want the formula to find the max cell (20) and then return the sum of the cells above it (5+10+15) as well as the cells below it (5+10+15). The range of values could be up to 20. thoughts??

Comment: From the sample, you want 60 as the response?

Comment: Once the maximum value is found, is it possible to add up the ENTIRE column where it is located? (eg: A1:A1048576)

Comment: What happens if the maximum number is found multiple times. For example if the values were  10, 15, 20, 15, 10, 5, 20, what result will you expect?

Comment: If there is only one maximum number, can you subtract the maximum value (20) from the total (5+10+15+20+15+10+5)?

Answer (score 0):

You could a combination of MATCH with MAX in the ADDRESS Function to get the address of the max value. From there put this in the SUM function with INDIRECT.  The image below is an example of this.

[image]

The formula shown in the screen cap. =SUM(A1:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(MAX(A1:A7),A1:A7,1)-1,1)))

Hopefully, this gives you some ideas.

Comment: this almost worked but still not exactly what i'm looking for.  See below

Comment: using the below table:

1 2
2 2
3 2
4 2
5 2
6 2
7 50
8 2
9 2
10 2
11 2
12 2
13 2
14 2
15 2

i want the formula to return the sum of cells 1 thur 6 (12).  Additionally, have another formula which returns the sum of cells 8 thru 15 (16).  All the while, the MAX cell could change from 7 to any other line.  Thoughts?

Comment: Isn't the max value at position 14 (50)

Comment: This might give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

This might help too. Just added some formula details, and the total below

[image]

Comment: this looks like it worked for you but its not for me?  My cells are not in column A.  could that be the problem?  Also, the cell with the values are formulas...could that be an issue too?

Comment: i was able to replicate your results when my values are in A1-A27 but this wont work for my sheet....any work around suggested?

Comment: Where are the values in your sheet? They formula will have to be updated from A1-A27 to match your source data

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `SUMIF` and `MAX` function:

```
=SUMIF(A1:A8,"<>" & MAX(A1:A8))
```

[image]